# Why must 'if' clause in Perl come with either curly brackets or nothing?

Tags: perl, if-statement, syntax

This is ok:

```
if ($some_var==$some_value) {}
```

This is ok too:

```
print "hello" if ($some_var==$some_value);
```

But this raises an error:

```
if ($some_var==$some_value) print "some_message";
```

Why must 'if' clause in Perl come with either curly brackets or nothing?

Comment: You are confused.  It can’t come with nothing.  The braces are mandatory. And for good reason.

Comment: If you want an `if` statement that does not take a block, why not use `and` as in `$some_var == $some_value and print "some message";` which is like the statement modifier form of `if` but with the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl has a rather complex syntax and is rather difficult to parse. I gather that curly brackets were made mandatory following an if clause so as to remove an ambiguity and make Perl code easier to parse.

Comment: Ambiguity removal, yes, but not ease of parsing; the parser (formerly yacc, now bison) trivially could be changed to not require the {}.

Comment: Well, Larry keeps talking about how he's refactored his grammar to reduce the number of productions in order to handle Perl syntax. That's what I meant by ease of parsing: the design of the productions.

Comment: It was done because  of the annoying C bug that braces are optional. Making them non-optional solves that bug.

Comment: I've been programming for 20+ years. I have made many, many, many coding errors in all that time. Messing up an else for an if statement, or forgetting brackets for a dependent block has got to be one of the rarest I've made. Do people really have such trouble getting this right????!

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the well-known problem in compiler construction known as a "dangling else". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Answer (score 6):

That's how the `perl` syntax is defined. The `if (expr) BLOCK` syntax requires a block, not a statement. See [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) ("Compound statements" section).

Excerpt:

> The if statement is straightforward. Because BLOCKs are always bounded by curly brackets, there is never any ambiguity about which if an else goes with.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($some_var==$some_value);` is not "ok too" when I try it (nor did I expect it to be).

Why is a BLOCK required, and a plain EXPR not allowed?  Because that's how Larry wanted it.

Comment: It's "ok" if you have a statement before it `print "hello!" if ($foo);`.

Comment: oops, sorry, this "if (clause);" is not ok

Comment: oh yes, but [print "hello" if (1==1);" is ok]

Comment: @nicola: You are completely missing the point by mixing statement modifiers with control flow constructs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the curlies, but Larry spoke mentioned that the *parens* could have been made optional. I believe he decided against it to keep the code readable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it simply isn't supported, this however is: `print "some_message" if($some_var == $some_value);`